# Firebird: Alter "anonymous" foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, firebird, firebird2.5

I need to alter an existing foreign key from "on delete restrict" to "on delete cascade". Unfortunaltey this bug sneaked through Q/A.

In my database I have several forign key relationships that were automatically named (INTEG_1, INTEG_2, ...). The name of  the constraint I have to fix is another in a new installation than in an Update from Version 2 and even another than when this Version 2 previously has been updated from Version 1.

As the referencing table only has one foreign key, this statement gives me the name of the constraint:

```
SELECT RDB$CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS
where RDB$CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' 
  and RDB$RELATION_NAME = 'MY_TABLE_NAME'
```

then I can drop and afterwards recreate the foreign key (with a "real" name this time)

```
alter table MY_TABLE_NAME 
drop constraint <result from above>;

alter table MY_TABLE_NAME
add constraint fk_my_table_name_purpose foreign key (other_id) 
      references other_table(id) on delete cascade;
```

However, I try to avoid working directly with system tables and I'd like to know whether there is a better / more elegant way to alter my foreign key.

Comment: "*try to avoid working directly with system tables*" - why? That's the official "API" to retrieve information like that (as Firebird does not have a standard `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`)

Comment: I saw system tables as something DB internal you CAN interact with, but shouldn't (if possible). But if my solution already is the "official way"... fine :-)

Comment: The advice not to work with system tables directly is about **modifying** the system tables. In Firebird it is technically possible to perform some forms of DDL by inserting, updating or deleting items from the system tables. This has its own set of problem, so Firebird 3 is going to make this impossible (with a few exceptions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no better way, the system tables are the only way to figure out the constraint name.

Comment: and this is completely legal way to obtain information about database structure.